# MySQL. where statement. query

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a script where loged in users just find the messages that are stored in the MySQL database with their usernames

```
('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE username = ' . $_SESSION['username'] . ' ')
```

The output. comes Unknown column 'John' in 'where clause'

Comment: This is not the query which is throwing you that error

Comment: @Mr.Alien: if `$_SESSION['username'] == 'John'`, it sure can be. He's not actually escaping that as a string, so it gets interpreted as a column name.

Comment: @DCoder It's a value and not a column name

Comment: As @Mr.Alien pointed out, there is another query which is causing the error. It could either be on the same page, or maybe through an `include`

Comment: @Mr.Alien: If `$_SESSION['username'] == 'John'`, the query sent to MySQL looks like this: `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE username = John`. There's no quotes around `John`, so it cannot be interpreted as a value.

Comment: @Mr.Alien MySQL will interpret an unquoted string as a column name.

Comment: @DCoder Ohh! If that's so, than this is the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is open to SQL injection. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php.

To answer your question. You are missing the double quotes around the username string.

```
('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE username = "' . $_SESSION['username'] . '" ')
                                          ^                             ^
```

Comment: Unless you're in ansi mode its single quotes.